# Number of levels in Binary Tree given the list of datas

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

Lets consider that, the following is the resultant of the Level Order Traversal of the Binary Tree.

Ex: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

But, I got a question like, with the given list of data, how to compute the total number of levels in the binary tree.

I thought some thing like, **Sqrt(8)** and doing the **Math.Round** to it, will yield the result.

But I doubt that, I am wrong.

May I know, what is the perfect to do that.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case, a binary tree with `n` nodes will have at least `1 + floor(log_2(n))` levels. For example, you can fit 7 nodes on 3 levels, but 8 nodes will take at least 4 levels no matter what.

Also in the general case, the upper limit is `n` levels in the case of a degenerate binary tree (which looks like a linked list hanging down from the root). Consider your example, where the level-order traversal (also known as breadth-first traversal) is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`. The following cases are possible, along with everything in between:

```
       1             1
      / \             \
     /   \             2
    2     3             \
   / \   / \             3
  4   5 6   7             \
 /                         4
8                           \
                             5
  (4 levels)                  \
                               6
                                \
                                 7
                                  \
                                   8
                      (8 levels)
```

There are [particular types of binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) for which you can put stronger constraints on the upper limit. For **complete** or **full** binary trees, the number of levels is always `1 + floor(log_2(n))`, because the shape of the tree depends only on `n`.

Answer (score 2):

If you label the nodes with an index in breadth-first order, you can compute the level without any traversal in O(1) time. So if you are doing multiple queries, you can do an O(N) BFT and have each query answered in O(1) time.

The formula for the level is:

```
level = floor(log(index + 1))
```

Where the log is to the base 2

This link help you [How can I calculate the level of a node in a perfect binary tree from its depth-first order index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721583/how-can-i-calculate-the-level-of-a-node-in-a-perfect-binary-tree-from-its-depth)

Answer (score 0):

The height of a complete binary tree is up to `O(logN)`.
Where `N` is the number of nodes you fill in the tree.

Note that Big O notation is required due to the fact that the actual height could vary by some addition or scaling factor.

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Trees/trees.html

Comment: Hi, You want to say that, log(no. of nodes) = height of the binary tree... I am unable to get it. log(8) yields a different value. Could you pls explain and add a bit more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just a matter of big O notation. Basically as a binary tree grows (increase in number of nodes), its maximum height converges closely to `log(N)`. As you can see a binary tree of 4 nodes may have a height of 2 or 3 levels. But `log(2)` base 2 is exactly 2 (the actual level exceeds the log value by 1). It's not an exact formula to calculate the height because it may vary Instead, as you increase the number of nodes over and over, the maximum height will closely converge. That's why it's `O (log N)` instead of exact term `log N`.

Answer (score 0):

Level index value **either** can starts from `0` or `1`.

If you are counting the level index starting **from 0** (i.e., Root at **Level 0**) then

```
#no.of levels = floor(log_2(n))
```

If you are counting the level index starting **from 1** (i.e., Root at **Level 1**) then

```
#no.of levels = 1 + floor(log_2(n))
```